# Two-join query is taking 540 seconds to run - how can I speed this up?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

A particular query is taking a *very* long time to run, around 540 seconds (yes, **9 minutes!**). This is causing load spikes.

Is there a way I can rewrite the query - or add indexes - to speed this up? 
    occurred.

#### Query

```
select DISTINCT tab3.id 
from `tab1`  
left join `tab2` on tab2.element_id = tab1.resource_id 
    and tab1.resource_type = 2 
    and tab2.element_type_id = 1 
left join `tab3` on tab2.tab3nt_id = tab3.id  
where tab1.group_tab1_id = 1 
    and tab1.domain_id = 2 
    and tab3.domain_id = 2 
    and tab3.tab3nt_start_date >= '2012-12-01'  
    and tab3.tab3nt_start_date <= '2013-03-01'
```

#### Explain Plan

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                       | key                        | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tab1   | ref    | group_tab1_id_resource_id,domain_id,domain_id_resource_type,tgtr_resource_domain_key | domain_id                  | 13      | const,const,const           |  962 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tab2   | ref    | FK_tab3nt,element_type_id_element_id                                                 | element_type_id_element_id | 8       | const,svr.tab1.resource_id  |   14 | Using where                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tab3   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,domain_id_tab3nt_type_cd                                                     | PRIMARY                    | 4       | svr.tab2.tab3nt_id          |    1 | Using where                               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+--------
```

#### Table Structure

```
mysql> show create table tab1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_tab1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resource_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resource_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `group_tab1_id_resource_id` (`group_tab1_id`,`resource_id`),
  KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`,`group_tab1_id`,`resource_type`,`resource_id`),
  KEY `domain_id_resource_type` (`domain_id`,`resource_type`),
  KEY `tgtr_resource_domain_key` (`resource_id`,`domain_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2039461 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show create table tab2\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab2` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `element_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tab3nt_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `element_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_tab3nt` (`tab3nt_id`),
  KEY `element_type_id_element_id` (`element_type_id`,`element_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53195543 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table tab3\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tab3
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `create_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tab3nt_type_cd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tab3nt_start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `tab3nt_end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tab3nt_user_FK` (`create_user_id`),
  KEY `domain_id_tab3nt_type_cd` (`domain_id`,`tab3nt_type_cd`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9393276 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't think your 540ms is spent in running this query only...what language are you using to run this query

Comment: @BhushanFirake If I read it correctly, it isn't **540 ms**, it is *540 sec*

Comment: @pvr please clarify -- is it 540 ***milliseconds*** or 540 ***seconds*** (9 minutes)? If it's 540 milliseconds, you might not get much of an improvement, especially if the database is remote.  If it's 9 minutes, something else is wrong as you're not selecting very many rows.

Comment: @DreamEater Ohh hell...my bad...never cared about ms or sec just assumed it is `ms`. Never took too much time for any query...Op  must have gone wrong at some other place...

Comment: it is running 540 seconds .

Comment: yes 9 minutes (540 seconds).

Comment: do you need a left outer join? try to make it an inner join, they usually executes faster...

Comment: hi @sine please send me the query.

Comment: a few further questions: does this query run that long if you enter it directly in a mysql client (command line), or are some other tools involved (do you process the query in a script and the 540 s are the script run time?). How big are the tables and how many lines make up the result set? A question to all: is int(255) even allowed?. And a remark: the tag sql-server referrers to the microsoft sql server, I think it is wrong here

Comment: directly in mysql command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing a simple (non-composite) index on tab2.element_id.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this Query because currently I don´t have access to a MySql Database but try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab3.id 
FROM 'tab1'
INNER JOIN 'tab2' 
      ON tab2.element_id = tab1.resource_id 
INNER JOIN 'tab3' 
      ON tab2.tab3nt_id = tab3.id
WHERE tab1.group_tab1_id = 1
    AND tab1.domain_id = 2
    AND tab3.domain_id = 2
    AND tab1.resource_type = 2
    AND tab2.element_type_id = 1
    AND tab3.tab3nt_start_date between '2012-12-01' and '2013-03-01'
```

Comment: use ` (backtick) instead of `'` with the table names. Also, a caveat: I think in this query `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` is a good optimization, but it's not always the way to go, as the two give different result sets. And finally: first test, then accept answer ;)

Comment: but query taking same long time.

Comment: I don´t know if it helps, but i updated the query in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Looking that you want different ids on table tab3, I would reorder tables and use inner join instead of left join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab3.id 
FROM 'tab3' 
INNER JOIN 'tab2'
  ON tab2.tab3nt_id = tab3.id 
INNER JOIN 'tab1'
  ON tab2.element_id = tab1.resource_id
WHERE tab1.group_tab1_id = 1 
AND tab1.domain_id = 2
AND tab3.domain_id = 2
AND tab1.resource_type = 2
AND tab2.element_type_id = 1
and tab3.tab3nt_start_date >= '2012-12-01'  
and tab3.tab3nt_start_date <= '2013-03-01'
```